# How to Translate this Image Source into Url.Content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**I have the following image which is rendered this way.**

```
  <img src="../../../..@Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Path@Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Filename" alt=""/>
```

I want if possible it's src attribute will be changed into Url.Content.

**What I have tried is this but my problem is it treats my model as string:**

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Path@Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Filename")" alt=""/>
```

Can anyone help me?

**The value of the Path and Filename is as follows:**

Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Path = "/Content/Uploads/FloorPlans/00004601/"
Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Filename = "testfloorplan.png"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found myself in a situation where I would need to format the string almost on any view,
so I made an extension method for this, just to get rid of those `String.Format`'s on every View.

```
public static class UrlHelpers
{
    public static string Content(this UrlHelper urlHelper,
                                 string formatPath, 
                                 params object[] args)
    {
        return urlHelper.Content(String.Format(formatPath, args));
    }
}
```

It just simply formats the specified path, nothing much going on, however calling it would be a bit nicer to read.

```
@{
    var path = Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Path;
    var imageName = Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Filename;
}
<img src="@Url.Content("~{0}{1}", path, imageName)"/>
```

Comment: I like this answer. Very elegant.

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand what you're going for. Try this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~{0}{1}", Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Path, Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Filename))" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/" + Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Path + Model.FloorPlan.Floor_Plan_Image_Filename)" alt="" />
```