# Concatenating strings in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How would I join two strings in Razor syntax?

If I had: `@Model.address` and `@Model.city` and I wanted the out put to be `address city` what would I do? Is it as simple as doing `@Model.address + " " + @Model.city`?

Comment: It cannot be more simple than that! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079254/how-to-translate-this-image-source-into-url-content/16080664#16080664

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Use the parentesis syntax of Razor:

```
@(Model.address + " " + Model.city)
```

or

```
@(String.Format("{0} {1}", Model.address, Model.city))
```

**Update**: With C# 6 you can also use the [$-Notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) (officially interpolated strings):

```
@($"{Model.address} {Model.city}")
```

Comment: These might be useful as well: [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) and  [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)

Comment: I found this useful when I was doing a string.Join inside of an @if clause. Inside the squiggly brackets, this didn't work:
`string.Join(",", Model.AppInfo.MailingCodes);`

but using the answer here, this did work:
`@(string.Join(",", Model.AppInfo.MailingCodes))`

Comment: It always feels a little weird when the answer is really old....

Answer (score 11):

String.Format also works in Razor:

```
String.Format("{0} - {1}", Model.address, Model.city)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can give like this....

```
<a href="@(IsProduction.IsProductionUrl)Index/LogOut">
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  ...
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address + " " + item.city) 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditBtn Href=@($"ProductAddEdit/{product.Id}") />
```

( Href is a parameter of my custom component EditBtn )

Answer (score -4):

the plus works just fine, i personally prefer using the concat function.

var s = string.Concat(string 1, string 2, string, 3, etc)