# How to concatenate two strings in image source with razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've defined the following variable in razor:

```
@{string imageRoot = "/_media/Images/";}
```

I'd like to use it here:

```
<img src="@imageRoot App1/MyImage.png"/>
```

The problem is the space within the string.

This will work but I'd like to keep the trailing slash in the variable instead of in the literal:

```
@{string imageRoot = "/_media/Images";}
<img src="@imageRoot/App1/MyImage.png"/>
```

Comment: Use [`@(imageRoot + "App1/MyImage.png")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106196/concatenating-strings-in-razor)

Comment: The problem is the quotes.  src="" has surrounding quotes.

Comment: It still works `src="@(imageRoot + "App1/MyImage.png")"`

Comment: The "+" gets translated as %20+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks a little ugly, but works:

```
@{string imageRoot = "/_media/Images/";}
<img src="@Html.Raw(imageRoot)App1/MyImage.png" />
```

Comment: Using Html.Raw() seems to be the only solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [String.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx) to merge the two string.

```
@{imgRoot = string.Concat(imgRoot,"/_media/Images");}
```

or just normal `imgRoot + = imgRoot + "/_media/Images"`
then set your variable as `<img src='@imageRoot'/>`
or `<img src="@{imageRoot+@"/App1/MyImage.png"}"/>`
Note that the @-symbol is a [Verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) and will prevent the \ from being escaped should you have a character that escapes your string