# How do I Combine Strings for Image Locations in MVC Core 2 Razor 3?

Tags: c#, razor, view, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I combine or concatenate images string for MVC Core 2 Razor?

```
Example:
Combine :  "~/images/" with 
Model.ImageLocation = "product1.jpg"
```

[How to concatenate two strings in image source with razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125068/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-image-source-with-razor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Code:`**

```
@model ElectronicsStore.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

    <img class="img" src="~/images/@(Model.ImageLocation)"/>

<dd>
```