# Concatenating strings in cshtml file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

How would I join two c# strings in cshtml file?

If I had: @Model.country and @Model.state and I wanted the out put to be country and state what would I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating strings in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106196/concatenating-strings-in-razor)

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

1. You can use `@(Model.Country + " " + Model.State)` or
2. with String concat function `@string.Concat(Model.Country, " ", Model.State)`
3. Add Readonly Property in ViewModel and use this property to display data. e.g:

   ```
     public class IndexViewModel
     {
         public string Country {get;set;}
         public string State {get;set;}
         public string CountryWithState => string.Concat(Country," ", State);
     }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly，If you want to put the value to input,or only want to show them,here is a demo:

```
    @Model.Country&nbsp;@Model.State
<input value="@Model.Country @Model.State" />
```

result:
[image]

If you want to get it in js,here is a demo:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var address = '@Model.Country@Model.State';
            console.log(address);
        })
    </script>
```

result:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Model.country + " " + Model.state)
```

Comment: A detailed explanation with your answer would help to understand the solution better. Please improve it.